# How to convert integer to char pointer in a function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently writing code that will read an xml file using the pugixml module. In my xml file I have several shape nodes that are differentiated by a shape_id attribute that gets a number.
For a specific need I have the shape_id number stored in an integer although in xml file the value of the respective attribute is of course a `string` (or `char`, have to check).

In order to retrieve the specific shape node, e.g. that with the attribute shape_id = 2 (just to give an example) I have written the function below.

pugixml provides a function `find_child_by_attribute()` with this call definition:

```
PUGI__FN xml_node xml_node::find_child_by_attribute(const char_t* name_, const char_t* attr_name, const char_t* attr_value) const
```

As you can see it requests the attribute value as a char pointer.

I manage to make it work with the two lines as in the code:

```
char char_shape_id = static_cast<char>(shape_id);
char* shape_id_ptr = &char_shape_id;
```

First I cast the integer `shape_id` into a char and then I take the address of this char and store it into a char pointer. I think it is an awkward way to do but I cannot figure out how to do this in a more elegant way.

I've tried following but failed.

```
char* shape_id_ptr = &(static_cast<char>(shape_id));
```

This seems to be invalid code.

What seems also to work is when I have following function call in the return line:

```
return root_node.child(sNodeNames.case_def_name.c_str()).find_child_by_attribute(sNodeNames.shape_name.c_str(),"item_id", (char*)shape_id);
```

I also tried to have a unique_ptr or shared_ptr instead of the raw char pointer but somehow I cannot figure out how to make this pointer cooperate with the `find_child_by_attribute()`. My shared pointer definition is currently

```
char char_shape_id = static_cast<char>(shape_id);
std::shared_ptr<char> shape_id_ptr(&char_shape_id);
```

but as I said, this is not accepted by the function.

```
//returns the node shape with a given shape_id number
pugi::xml_node nXml::tXmlShape::GetShapeNode(const int shape_id, const pugi::xml_node& root_node)
{
    char char_shape_id = static_cast<char>(shape_id);
    char* shape_id_ptr = &char_shape_id;

    nXml::sXmlNodeNames sNodeNames;
    nXml::sXmlShapeTypes sShapeTypes;
    return root_node.child(sNodeNames.case_def_name.c_str()).find_child_by_attribute(sNodeNames.shape_name.c_str(),"item_id", shape_id_ptr);
}
;
```

Apart from the pretty ugly return line phrasing is there a more elegant way to accomplish the transmission of a char pointer of an originally integer value to the function and how could I realize this with a `unique_ptr` respectively `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Not only is that an "awkward way", it is likely that this will fail miserably, when it's time to actually test if it works. Something that expects a plain `char` pointer is likely expecting a well-formed, `'\0'`-terminated string. And not a pointer to one, plain, unadorned `char` value. If you need to represent an integer value as a string, the way to do this, in C++, is to use `std::to_chars`.

Comment: mh. My Microsoft VS 2019 doesn't find ```std::to_chars``` (I've included ```<iostream>``` and ```<charconv>```).

Comment: It's not very complicated. It would take maybe 10-20 lines of code to implement to_chars yourself.

Comment: @ManyQuestions it should have integer to_chars from VS 2017 15.7. You can also use `to_string` but it'd still be advisable to figure out your environment. Perhaps you forgot to add `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++latest` flag to get features from newer standards.

Comment: @Dan M. Thanks! I will check this and try to figure out how to apply this flag (I am pretty new to C++ coding (started to code in January this year) and to the compiler I am using (MS VisualStudio 2019). Wierd that it does not offer this functionality directly. It allows the inclusion of <charconv> without issues.

Comment: -- OK I figured out how to set MSVS2019 to C++17 standard (which is apparantly not the default C++ standanrd in this compiler 8O)

Comment: Another question (I have many :) ): It seems that ```std::to_chars``` requires to have the number of digits fixed. Is this correct?

Comment: I finally resorted to use this ```std::to_string``` + ```.c_str()``` approach as described here: https://www.delftstack.com/de/howto/cpp/how-to-convert-int-to-char-array-in-cpp/ It does what I want and I do not have to hard code the maximum digit number of my ```int```. Also it seems that the ```std::to_chars``` method requires this string to initialized with some appropriate characters in order not get some wierd character chain if the number of digits of my ```int``` is less than the maximum number.

Comment: @ManyQuestions It doesn't require any of that. Your int already has fixed length. It can't have more than 9 digits (+ 1 for sign and +1 for nul terminated char). You can init the buffer with 0, but you also don't have to since to_chars the pointer to the one-past-the end element of your number so if you need to pass it to the function expecting a C string you can just write '\0' to that pointer. Anyway, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars has more than enough info.